# Unable to add trait bounds to member of a struct

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm attempting to add use `std::io::Cursor` with a generic type `R`, but retain the `Read` type bounds so that `Read` trait is accessible, and subsequently can support `bytes()` method.

Here is my struct definition so far:

```
struct Parse<'parse, R: Read + BufRead + 'parse> {
    tokens: Vec<Token>,
    source: Cursor<&'parse mut R>,
}
```

Assuming I have a variable `parser` that's an instance of `Parse`, I want to be able to call `parser.source.bytes()`. `bytes()` is a method provided by `Read`. Despite the annotation around `R`, the compiler is telling me that `R` isn't satisfying the `std::io::Read` trait bounds.

Here is that snippet of code in context along with a [direct link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d32e07bd8855583b62069bd4643f22ba&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
// using Cursor because it tracks position internally
use std::io::{Cursor, Read, BufRead};

struct Token {
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}

struct Parse<'parse, R: Read + BufRead + 'parse> {
    tokens: Vec<Token>,
    source: Cursor<&'parse mut R>,
}

impl<'parse, R: Read + BufRead + 'parse> Parse <'parse, R> {
    fn new(source: &'parse mut R) -> Self {
        Parse {
            tokens: vec!(),
            source: Cursor::new(source),
        }
    }

    fn parse_primitive(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<Token> {
        let start = self.source.position();
        let bytes = self.source.bytes();                     // <- error raised here

        // dummy work
        for _ in 0..3 {
            let byte = bytes.next().unwrap().unwrap()
        }
        let end = self.source.position();
        Ok(Token { start: start as usize, end: end as usize})
    }
}

fn main() {
    //...
}
```

Generates the following error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `bytes` found for type `std::io::Cursor<&'parse mut R>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:33
   |
24 |         let bytes = self.source.bytes();
   |                                 ^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `bytes` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::io::Cursor<&mut R> : std::io::Read`
           `&mut std::io::Cursor<&'parse mut R> : std::io::Read`
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the notes after the error messages:

```
= note: the method `bytes` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
        `std::io::Cursor<&mut R> : std::io::Read`
        `&mut std::io::Cursor<&'parse mut R> : std::io::Read`
```

The [`Read` implementation for `Cursor<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#impl-Read) is only defined when `T: AsRef<[u8]>`. If you add that constraint then the `Read` implementation will be available:

```
impl<'parse, R: AsRef<[u8]> + BufRead + 'parse> Parse <'parse, R> {
```

You will still have a few other errors in that code. But this should answer your surface question.

Comment: Ah of course. I will mark this answer as correct when I have implemented it in my own code, but that certainly makes lots of sense!

Comment: Making that change appears to result in the same error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5b15369c7f9afc07460120fa0fbfc848&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @TimMcNamara Oops! That was a little typo. It should have been `AsRef<[u8]>`.

Comment: Thanks for being so responsive Peter. You were also very correct about there being other errors. It looks like using Cursor was the wrong approach entirely.

Comment: @TimMcNamara Perhaps the wrong approach. One problem is that `bytes()` will consume the cursor.